# how to get same value from different rows using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and 1 table.table name is : cranetype they have 4 fields   (cf_did,cf_firstname, cf_comment,cf_cranetype) .

database values below.

```
cf_did  cf_firstname cf_comment   cf_cranetype 

1       Alexy         tfhgfnjh       2,3    
2       Thomas        fdghfgh       11,6,3  
3       Thomas         cgjkjhl      5,6,11,3        
4       Thomasxc       cgjkjhl      1,6,9,4         
5       Thomaseg       fdghgh       11,12,3     
6       Thomasm        fsgdfgbd     11,6,3  
7       Thomabs        dgtrty       7,9,11  
8       Rdgfghfdg      bfdhh        1,3,4   
9       Gngfdytyt      eertret      1,6,3   
10      Dvbgfj         hfdhhyrtyr   6,3     
11      Hnfhghyt       bfgfdhg      11,6,3  
12      Adgfdyh      dfsdtrst        1  
13      Rida       gfhgfjgh         3,7,68
```

I have a select box, they have values `(1,2,3,4,...)`.
If I select value 1 from select box.

I want to check database table(cranetype)  field `cf_cranetype`.

E.g :

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cranetype` WHERE `cf_cranetype`='1'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    <?Php echo $row['cf_did'];?>
}
```

I want output like this:

```
if cf_cranetype =1.
4,8,9,12. (these are cf_did)
```

My code is:

```
$cranetype = $_POST['cranetype'];
$words = explode(',', $cranetype);
if (strlen($cranetype) > 0) {
    $Where = '';
    foreach ($words as $Item) {
        $Where = "cf_cranetype LIKE '%$Item%' AND";
    } 
    $Where = substr($Where, 0, -4);
    $list_ul = "(SELECT * FROM cf_directory` WHERE $Where)";
    $query = mysql_query($list_ul) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: my code is `$cranetype=$_POST['cranetype'];
$words = explode(',',$cranetype);
if (strlen($cranetype) > 0) {  $Where = '';
   foreach($words as $Item) { 
     $Where="cf_cranetype LIKE '%$Item%' AND"; }
  $Where = substr($Where,0,-4);$list_ul="(SELECT * FROM `cf_directory` WHERE $Where)"; $query = mysql_query($list_ul) or die(mysql_error());}}`

Answer (score 2):

A solution is using `find_in_set` and `group_concat`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cf_did) as cf_dids
FROM `cranetype` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', `cf_cranetype`) > 0;
```

### Demo:

```
create table cranetype(cf_did int,  cf_firstname varchar(100), cf_comment varchar(100),  cf_cranetype varchar(50)); 
insert into cranetype values
(4,       'Thomasxc',       'cgjkjhl',      '1,6,9,4'),         
(7,       'Thomabs',        'dgtrty',       '7,9,11'),  
(8,       'Rdgfghfdg',      'bfdhh',        '1,3,4'),   
(9,       'Gngfdytyt',      'eertret',      '1,6,3'),
(12,      'Adgfdyh',      'dfsdtrst',        '1');

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cf_did) as cf_dids
FROM `cranetype` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', `cf_cranetype`) > 0;
```

### Output：

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cf_did) as cf_dids
    -> FROM `cranetype`
    -> WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', `cf_cranetype`) > 0;
+----------+
| cf_dids  |
+----------+
| 4,8,9,12 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: but one more question? how to use this code SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cf_did) as cf_dids
    -> FROM `cranetype`
    -> WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', `cf_cranetype`) > 0;  to display cf_did, cf_firstname ,cf_comment(all fields) values..if this code display only cf_did value.

Comment: Replace `GROUP_CONCAT(cf_did) as cf_dids` with `cf_did, cf_firstname ,cf_comment`.

Answer (score 0):

use Find_in_set() in mysql.

```
SELECT * FROM cranetype WHERE FIND_IN_SET ('1',cf_cranetype);
```

Comment: Find_in_set() : It Does not give proper result. for example if we have to search 3 then its does not show for 13

Comment: if cf_cranetype =1.
4,8,9,12. (these are cf_did). This is your result which you want. So i gave this query

Comment: SELECT * FROM cranetype WHERE  `cf_cranetype` LIKE '%1%'; use this format of LIKE Query

Comment: if i select cf_cranetype=11.how to get all rows (cf_did). from table ,like 2,3 5,6,7 ,11

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [FIND_IN_SET](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php). Please check link for more explanation.
here your query is

**`SELECT * FROM cranetype WHERE FIND_IN_SET ('1',cf_cranetype);`**
[image]

Comment: im use this code, but no output,i got error message FUNCTION database name.FIND_IN_SET does not exist

Comment: I have checked in my local its working fine. @Alexyui

Comment: sir, i use this codeSELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cf_did) as cf_dids
FROM `cranetype` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', `cf_cranetype`) > 0; and i got  correct answer . cf_dids  |
          +----------+
         | 4,8,9,12 |  how to display cf_did, cf_firstname ,cf_comment(all fields) values..if this code display only cf_did value.